# Bolt CMS: add entry/block in editor/wysiwyg

Tags: bolt-cms

Is there a possibility to add a block or an entry within editor/wysiwyg?

Something like:

```
Random text...
{contenttype: 'block', slug: 'block1', template: _block_tmpl.twig}
...Random text
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to add twig tags inside the admin editor.

You can define a custom page template for you page and add a reference to your block directly in your template.